# getcookies() null pointer exception

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I wrote this Code to check and create a cookie.It loops through the array returned by the request object.But it throws exception.It's thrown at the beginning of the for loop.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CookieLogin extends HttpServlet {
    PrintWriter out;    
    boolean flag;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException{
                Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
                out = res.getWriter();              
                for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
                    if(cookies[i].getName().equals("session_started")){
                        flag=true;
                        out.println("Your session started on "+cookies[i].getValue());
                    }
                }
                if(!flag){
                    String time = new java.util.Date().toString();
                    res.addCookie(new Cookie("session_started",time));
                    out.println("just started");
                }
    }
}
```

Here's the Stack Trace from eclipse.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CookieLogin.doPost(CookieLogin.java:11)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There is no cookie in your request it seems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.getCookies()` returned `null`,so `cookies.length` throws NullPointerException,

you should check wheather the `req.getCookies();` is `null`;

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException is because getCookies() method will return null if there are no cookies. And so it throws a NullPointerException.

Solution:Check for *null*

```
for(int i=0;cookies!=null&&i<cookies.length;i++)
```